# How come my pycharm IDE doesn't have a shortcut to make a flask project anymore?

Tags: pycharm

[image]

When I click on new project it doesn't show all the "presets", like create a flask project on the left hand side like it used to. I can't figure out why.
I'm using the community edition.

You can look at this video to get an idea of what I mean at 1:20.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEJZpA1bhoU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using PyCharm Community Edition which doesn't have Flask support on board, see the comparison matrix https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=pycharm&product=pycharm-ce